# MS Access Calc Field with combined fields

Tags: ms-access, field, ms-access-2013

I have been trying to resolve this calc field issue for about 30 mins, it looks like I have the single field conditions correct in the expression such as [points] and [contrib] but the combined ([points]+[contrib]) field is not meeting the requirement that sets the field to the correct member type, so when these are added it returns some other member type as basic. Might I use the between operator with the added fields...? I tried it, but there is some compositional error. So in other words if you got 45 points it sets you to basic only named in the points field, if you have contrib of 45 you are set to basic in the calc field as expected, but if it were 50 + 50, instead it is setting to basic when it should be "better" member label. Otherwise this simple statement should seem to be correct but the computer is not reading it so when adding. It must not be recognizing the combined value for some reason and calc fields do not have a sum() func.
Focus here: (([points]+[Contrib]) >= 45 And ([points]+[Contrib]) < 100),"Basic",

```
IIf(([points] >=45 And [points]<100) Or ([Contrib] >=45 And [Contrib] <100) Or (([points]+[Contrib]) > = 45 And ([points]+[contrib] < 100),"Basic",
IIf(([points] >=100 And [points] <250) Or ([Contrib] >=100 And [Contrib] <250) Or ((([points]+[Contrib]) >=100) And (([points]+[Contrib])<250)),"Better",
IIf(([points] >=250 And [points]<500) Or ([Contrib] >=250 And [Contrib] <500) Or ((([points]+[Contrib]) >=250) And (([points]+[Contrib])<500)),"Great",
IIf(([points] >=500) Or ([Contrib] >=500) Or (([points]+[Contrib]) >=500),"Best","Non-member"))))
```

Comment: This is hard to follow, but is there a specific error message? Note that the last expressions (after "Focus here:") are not equivalent. Between is inclusive, so includes 44 and 100 (50+50).

Comment: Rather than this complicated expression though, I would set up a small table and lookup the member status. This should be possible, matching points and Contrib where they fall between specific boundaries.

Comment: Please ignore the first part that uses the between, that was an experiment. The range should be >= 45 to < 100. However the compiler is not using the sum of the two fields, it reads only one at a time which is why this is so complicated. I did look at the table and where these boundaries are. It works up until the adding and I am not sure why. I will edit.

Comment: In the uppermost line, there is an extra parenthesis in `([points]+[Contrib])`.

Comment: It belongs in the table, it updates as the points are entered. The past points and contrib are not updating as it should to the correct level of labels with the sum of the given points and contrib.

Comment: I tried using it without the extra parenthesis before, it is just meant to organize the order of adding as a component of the expression to prevent segmenting the code incorrectly. It should just read over them.

Comment: Access doesn't "just read over" parenthesis.

Comment: Ok, I will give it another try. Simple desire it to add just those.

Comment: Still did not work but it does read the fields separately based on the conditions.

Comment: It is a calculated field from Access 2013

Comment: The way I use parenthesis is in a manner of listing operands and operations it should not interfere, it is just an order to read those in. I removed them it made no difference. It must be how it reads the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a data sample from an Access 2010 table which includes a calculated field named *member_type*:

```
id points Contrib member_type
-- ------ ------- ----------
 1      1       1 Non-member
 2     50       1 Basic
 3    200       1 Better
 4    300       1 Great
 5    600       1 Best
```

If that is what you want for your calculated field, here is the expression I used for *member_type*:

```sql
IIf([points]+[Contrib]>=45 And [points]+[Contrib]<100,'Basic',IIf([points]+[Contrib]>=100 And [points]+[Contrib]<250,'Better',IIf([points]+[Contrib]>=250 And [points]+[Contrib]<500,'Great',IIf([points]+[Contrib]>=500,'Best','Non-member'))))
```

In case I didn't get it exactly correct, here is that same expression formatted so that you can better see where you need changes:

```sql
IIf([points]+[Contrib]>=45 And [points]+[Contrib]<100,'Basic',
IIf([points]+[Contrib]>=100 And [points]+[Contrib]<250,'Better',
IIf([points]+[Contrib]>=250 And [points]+[Contrib]<500,'Great',
IIf([points]+[Contrib]>=500,'Best','Non-member'
))))
```

Note if either *points* or *Contrib* is Null, *member_type* will display *"Non-member"*.  If that is not the behavior you want, you will need a more complicated expression.  Since a calculated field expression can not use `Nz()`, you would have to substitute something like `IIf([points] Is Null,0,[points])` for every occurrence of `[points]` and `IIf([Contrib] Is Null,0,[Contrib])` for `[Contrib]`

It would be simpler to prohibit Null for those fields (set their *Required* property to *Yes*) and set *Default Value* to zero.

Comment: Great work but we are not quite there yet. If there are nulls in one field it will not add, and therefore you need to do what I did before, an individual expression for that field which must have muddled it up somewhere.

Comment: I think my solution is to do what you have there but query to fill in nulls as 0 to make it calculate something instead of nothing when it adds.

Answer (score 0):

The BETWEEN operator returns TRUE if the value you are testing is >= or <= the limits you have for BETWEEN.

If you are looking at 50+50 then that total = 100 and you are Between 44 and 100. That would result in an answer of "Basic".  Change the range for ([points]+[Contrib]) Between 44 And 100) to be ([points]+[Contrib]) Between 44 And 99)

Comment: Yes I tried that and it wont read the code... not sure why. It might be because of the mix of syntaxes? That should not matter.

Comment: I just tried this and it works: zz: IIf((([points]+[Contrib])>=45) And (([points]+[contrib])<80),"Yes","No").  It is adding points + contrib just fine.  Be extra careful with your parenthesis.

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate another nested one to check it will do it? It would not eval both the individual ones and the combined so I added those. Try it to see it it compiles. Maybe there is a loose parenthesis somewhere confusing the steps.

Comment: What I might do is try to erase other levels of members and start with one at a time and nest these carefully again....